# JQuery Cookie loads but returns error always

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I just get:

```
8:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

for:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
    $.cookies.set('TEST', "VALUEEEE", { path: '/' }); // <-- errs here
</script>
```

I'm in MVC5, tried this directly on a page, in layout, in partial.... no go anywhere... simply get this error no matter what. File is in place from NuGet package and referenced as you see here... Confirmed jQuery loaded, and jquery cookie file loaded...

[image: Screenshot]

Cannot get this to work... any ideas?

Comment: is it `Cookies` (with capital `C`) ?

Comment: "var config = $.cookie = function..." don't think so  https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: never mind, docs (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) indicate you need to use something like `$.cookie('name', 'value');` - there is no `.set(..)`

Comment: bingo... make it a post and I'll mark as answer.  All the examples I saw has .cookies.set I shoulda read the main doc more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for the library indicate usage to be like this:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

There is no `.set(...)` function

Comment: There is a side-effect due to the backwards compatibility attempt where in [version 1.5.1](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v1.5.1) where you can use the `.set` method in the `$.cookie` namespace, but that is not documented and therefore it should not be used [in any circumstance](https://medium.com/@fagnerbrack/library-internals-do-not-exist-1ff50a30e3b0).

Answer (score 2):

It should be like below

```
var cook = $.cookie('TEST', "VALUEEEE", { path: '/' });
```